# Unable to run unit tests for openstack nova

Tags: python, unit-testing, virtualenv, openstack, openstack-nova

I was able to create the virtual environment for nova to run Unit tests. At least it said so.

```
Nova development environment setup is complete.
Nova development uses virtualenv to track and manage Python dependencies
while in development and testing.
To activate the Nova virtualenv for the extent of your current shell
session you can run:
.....
```

But when i tried to run the particular unit test cases, eg:

./run_tests.sh test_libvirt

it's failing saying :

```
Running `tools/with_venv.sh python -m nova.openstack.common.lockutils python setup.py testr --testr-args='--subunit --concurrency 0  test_libvirt'`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/chinmay/nova/nova/openstack/common/lockutils.py", line 29, in <module>
    from oslo.config import cfg
**ImportError: No module named config**
Ran 0 tests in 0.006s
OK
```

Is the virtaul environment not set properly ? oslo.config in in the env. i did 
`source .venv/bin/activate` and tried again, but the same result.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `oslo.config` and install it again in your virtual environment. This might solve your problem :)

Comment: Yes. tried it. I am suspecting the env was not configured properly. 
after that i had to run

testr init

now i'm able to run the unit tests. Thnanks

Comment: If this solve your problem then select it as answer ;)